# How to divide multi digit number into fewer digit number in Python?

Tags: python

I want divide a 8-digit number into parts with a 4 digit. pls help

```
def div4(a, n = 4):
    return [a [i*4: (i + 1) * 4] for i in range (len(a) // n)]
```

i tried this but it wont work

Answer (score 1):

You can use stdlib [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
>>> divmod(12345678, 10**4)
(1234, 5678)
```

Generalizing this idea:

```
>>> def div(a, n=4):
...     if a < 0:
...         result = div(-a, n)
...         result[0] *= -1
...         return result
...     p = 10 ** n
...     results = []
...     while a >= p:
...         a, b = divmod(a, p)
...         results.append(b)
...     results.append(a)
...     return results[::-1]
...
>>> div(12345678, 4)
[1234, 5678]
>>> div(123456789012, 4)
[1234, 5678, 9012]
>>> div(123456789012, 2)
[12, 34, 56, 78, 90, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use strings and slices to solve this:

```
def parts(m, n=4):
  return [int(s[start:start+piece_length])
          for s in (str(m),)
          for piece_length in (len(s) // n,)
          for i in range(n)
          for start in (i * piece_length,)]

parts(12345678)
# [12, 34, 56, 78]

parts(12345678, 2)
# [1234, 5678]
```